# Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: bio, blog, describtion, id, image, speciality, status, user, user_id

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

hey i want to create a profile page for my user,in which when people logging to the website they can view the profile of every user,i get the above error anytime i tried to log on to every profile of the user i get it, this is my code below

### views.py

```
class DoctorDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Doctor
    fields = ['user', 'email', 'image', 'speciality', 'bio']
    template_name = 'pages/doctor_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(Doctor, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Doctor.objects.filter(doctor=user.doctor)
```

### urls.py

```
    path('doctor/', doctor, name='doctor'),
    path('doctor/info/<str:username>', user_views.DoctorDetailView.as_view(), name='doctor-detail'),
```

### doctor.html

```
<a href="{% url 'doctor-detail' doc.user.username %}"><div class="img-wrap d-flex align-items-stretch">
                                <div class="img align-self-stretch" style="background-image: url({{ doc.user.doctor.image.url }}"></div>
```

### models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Status(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length=5)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="doctor")
    image = models.ImageField(default='jazeera.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.TextField()
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    describtion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.ManyToManyField(Status)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `user = get_object_or_404(Doctor, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))` be `user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))` (so with the `User` model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Doctor` object has no username, hence:

```
user = get_object_or_404(Doctor, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

makes not much sense, you however do not need to use `get_object_or_404` to fetch the user first, you can filter with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class DoctorDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Doctor
    fields = ['user', 'email', 'image', 'speciality', 'bio']
    template_name = 'pages/doctor_detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Doctor, user__username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

Comment: after this solution do i need to make any changes to my url.py because i get this error, Generic detail view DoctorDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Comment: @Chosenbrain: ah yes, since it is a `SingleObjectMixin`, Then you probably better override `get_object`.

Comment: how do i get to that sir ??

Comment: to be honest its not clear to me kindly make it clear because you actually provided 2 answers the first comment and the second edit i dont know if i am to write both

Comment: @Chosenbrain: you remove `get_queryset`, and implement `get_object` instead as in the answer.